# AES 128 CBC Mode decrypt data coming wrong format

Tags: ios, swift, encryption

I'm using this code for Decryption

```
let iv = ""
let key = "e5dozUC1fLIX5FBh"
let input = "2307e05b6b87f613ef16a500d792c800ca44e6a8b3e9e5b18a048bba802ef9aee8950d9bc37faf995918dcfd10c6e81f99bf582c802dd6dd2709ad93e19c23ef"

let values = HexStr.encryptDES(byKey: input) as Data

let aes = try AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .CBC, padding: NoPadding())

//Converting to hex   
let ciphertext = try aes.decrypt (Array<UInt8>(hex: input))
let str = String(data: Data(ciphertext), encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)    
return str!
```

Output coming Like this

> &"Vnszt%!unt doesn't exists. Please register with  app.","code":401}

Unformatted data coming like this

> "&"Vnszt%!unt"

How to get original get full original data?

Comment: is the code using `CryptoSwift`?

Comment: Yes..let me know wt's problem it is there..i tried from yesterday..please help.

Comment: Android side working fine..but iOS not working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it decrypts like:

> \u{1E}\u{17}\t\n\t&\"V\u{03}nsz{)b\u{0C}ata found.\",\"code\":401,\"android_version\":\"1\"}

Though it has some of unreadable contents, decrypted text certainly contains valid plaintext.

I do not believe only half of the whole text can mistakenly broken by some misused settings. Thus, in my *personal opinion*, this is a valid decryption.